# Product Price down callback for Amazon API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I am looking for api which make callback request when amazon ecommerce product price change or get down.

I have searched it on Amazon API Doc and Amazon MWS.
Asking for the same feature which Ebay provide:
Ex. https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/guides/ebayfeatures/Notifications/Notif-ItemRevised.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the [AnyOfferChangedNotification](https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/notifications/Notifications_AnyOfferChangedNotification.html).  If you subscribe to this notification, you will get notified via Amazon SQS when any price in the top 20 offers for a product changes.  This only applies to products that you sell on your own account.